# Is it possible to have a linear transformation that shifts a given matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, linear-transformations, matrix-equations

Suppose I have a matrix A. I understand that I could for example rotate the vectors, shear, and flip them. But how could I move the entire matrix left or right?

Comment: What do you mean by "move the matrix"? Could you give an example?

Comment: @DanielHast the entry [-2,1] has been moved right 3 and up 1, so it is now [1,2]. it is basically x+3,y+1, im just not sure how i would describe this transformation in a matrix

Comment: The function $f(x,y)=(x+3,y+1)$ is not a linear transformation.

Comment: Learn about an affine transformation, which is a linear transformation followed by a translation. Your transformation is a translation, which is the same as the identity linear transformation followed by a translation.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is encountered in robotics, where rigid motions, i.e. rotations + translations can be expressed in just a matrix form, called "homogeneous transformations". Here, an example:

Given the affine mapping $f(x)=Ax+b$, define the followings homogeneous variable of $x$ as:

$x'=\begin{bmatrix}
x\\1
\end{bmatrix}$

You can verify that, if $y=Ax+b$, then:

$y'=\begin{bmatrix}
y\\1
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
A&b\\0&1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x\\1
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
Ax+b\\1
\end{bmatrix}$.

Therefore,  $M=\begin{bmatrix}
A&b\\0&1
\end{bmatrix}$ is the matrix you are looking for. Be careful, since the homogeneous coordinates of a vector requires  the dimension of your variable to be increased by 1. This algebraic trick has a beautiful geometric interpretation. Have a look on Projective Geometry if you are interested in it!